Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'
I'm not able to solve this issue two days already. I'm working on my first MAUI Hybrid-Blazor application which has local SQLite database.
I'm getting the following error message:

"[*] - SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'. -    at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)\n   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionInternal..ctor(SqliteConnectionStringBuilder connectionOptions, SqliteConnectionPool pool)\n   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionPool.GetConnection()\n   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionFactory.GetConnection(SqliteConnection outerConnection)\n   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.Open()\n   at System.Data.Common.DbConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---\n   at TheBoss.Services.ServiceData.GetAllCryptocurrenciesAsync() in C:\Users\User\Desktop\TheBoss\TheBoss\TheBoss\Services\ServiceData.cs:line 26 - [4/7/2024 9:33:57 PM]"

I made separate console application just to make sure I'm not doing something wrong with the query or database, but everything is working as suppose in the console application. I can connect to the database and execute the query.
Is there any additional setting that I'm missing? Any help is appreciated.
ServiceData.cs
public class ServiceData
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;
    public ServiceData(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(connectionString));
    }

    public async Task<List<Cryptocurrency>?> GetAllCryptocurrenciesAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var items = new List<Cryptocurrency>();

            using (var connection = new SqliteConnection($"Data Source={_connectionString}"))
            {
                await connection.OpenAsync();

                using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM cryptocurrencies;";

                    using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                    {
                        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
                        {
                            var item = new Cryptocurrency
                            {
                                Id = reader.GetInt32(0),
                                Name = reader.GetString(1),
                                Icon = reader.GetString(2)
                            };
                            items.Add(item);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return items;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Append the exception details to the exceptions file
            string exceptionmsg = $"[*] - {ex.Message} - {ex.StackTrace} - [{DateTime.Now}]";

            return null;
        }
    }

MauiProgram.cs
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        private static readonly string _databasePath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "Data/theboss.db");
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                });

            // Add SQLite connection
            var connectionStringBuilder = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                DataSource = $"Data Source= " + _databasePath
            };
            var connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString);
            builder.Services.AddSingleton(connection);


            builder.Services.AddMauiBlazorWebView();

#if DEBUG
            builder.Services.AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools();
            builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }



I did some troubleshooting but still not able to resolve it:
string databasePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Data", "theboss.db");
"/data/user/0/com.theboss.myapp/files/Data/theboss.db"
Exception: Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'.
 

string databasePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "theboss.db3");
"/data/user/0/com.theboss.myapp/files/theboss.db3"
Exception: {Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: cryptocurrencies'.

 


AppDataDirectory does not point to files that are bundled in your app

In which directory the database file should be?

I’d try using “./data/“ if the file has a Content build action.  Note that bundled files are read-only

Have you found a solution?

When migrating from Xamarin to MAUI I had to change the path to .db file. In Xamarin I had Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments). In MAUI I had to change to: Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
